# Display dynamic html pages in browser using jsp/servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I want to display html files dynamically (last modified at the top) using JSP/Servlet.
Please help me .

Comment: can you explain your requirement bit more

Comment: in one folder we are storing html documents, in my browser i want to display last updated 3 documents

Answer (score 2):

- You will have list of file in your DIR. so using [`listFiles()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) retrieve all files.
- Take them in Collection.
- Implement a Comparator and use [`lastModified()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29) to compare and sort . and take first n files and display
- Put this logic in service classes and call them from servlet